# How to connect/open to Couchbase web interface of remote machine

Tags: ssh, localhost, couchbase

I am trying to connect to couchbase web interface of remote machine through ssh. so that i can open web interface of couchbase of that remote machine in my Ubuntu OS.

I try something like this , but it doesn't work for me

```
ssh -L 8091:robi:80 robi@xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

Can someone help me how to achieve this.  I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8091 is not the only port you need to forward. Maybe just configure VPN?

Full list of ports you can find in the docs
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/security/security-iptables.html